# Restrict values to ant Property task

Tags: ant

What is the simplest implementation to restrict values to a property?

```
property name="prop_name"  value="${dynamic_value}
```

I want to have the values to `${dynamic_value}` from a restricted set.

Thanks,
Wajid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a scriptcondition (see [ant manual conditions](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html)) with builtin javascript engine
(included in Java >= 1.6.x), f.e. :

```
<project>
 <property name="foo" value="26"/>
 <fail message="Value of $${foo} not in range => [${foo}] !">
  <condition>
   <scriptcondition language="javascript">
    var foo = parseInt(project.getProperty("foo"));
    self.setValue(foo &lt;= 20 || foo &gt;= 25);
   </scriptcondition>
 </fail>
</project>
```

Comment: Thanks this helped though i had to use a modified version of it for string comparison

`<property name="check_Env" value="${deployment.plan.environment}"/>`

Comment: `<property name="check_Env" value="${deployment.plan.environment}"/>
 <fail message="Value of $${check_Env} not in range (prod, dev, test) => [${check_Env}] !">
   <condition>
    <scriptcondition language="javascript">
  var check_Env = project.getProperty("check_Env");
  self.setValue(true);
  if(check_Env == "prod" || check_Env == "test" || check_Env == "dev"){
   self.setValue(false);
  }
    </scriptcondition>
 </condition>
</fail>`

Comment: forgot that the default value of scriptconditon is false, so simply use <scriptcondition language="javascript" value="true"> and delete the line self.setValue(true); inside your scriptcondition